# Dynamic Website CSS Rollover - 100% DIV Height inside DIV with CSS display=table-cell

Tags: html, css

I think I may be the one of the 1000's looking for this answer.. but no one seems to be able to answer it..
I have a dynamic website that I am trying to get a 100% height div inside another div with the class=table-cell.. I'm actually trying to create rollover effect using pure css.. and the div inside a td isn't working..

I have setup a JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/RedEarthDesigns/uwXf6/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="div-table">
    <div class="div-td venue">
        <div class="hidden"><span><h1>Venue Name</h1><p>Venue Address</p><p>Venue Website</p> <p>More Info</p></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-td venue">
        <div class="hidden"><span><h1>Venue Name</h1><p>Venue Address</p><p>Venue Website</p><p>More Info</p></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400, 300);
 body {
    margin:0;
    font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-color:#111;
}
p {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#eee;
    line-height: 6px;
}
h1 {
    font-size:24px;
    color:#eee;
}
.div-table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.div-row {
    display:table-row;
}
.div-td {
    display:table-cell;
    height:33%;
    width:20%;
    text-align:right;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.hidden span {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width:auto;
    vertical-align:text-bottom;
    padding:10px;
    transform:translate(9999px);
    opacity:0;
}
.hidden:hover span {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width:auto;
    vertical-align:text-bottom;
    padding:10px;
    display:block;
    transform:translate(0);
    opacity:1;
}
.venue {
    background-image:url(http://www.indpg.com.au/img/norman.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.div-td:hover {
    background-image:none;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Add a fiddle if possible, it will be easy to solve, and one more thing I have saw in your code is, whenever you giving Min-height or Max-height, dont use height on same class or ID

Comment: cool! never used it before.. i'll have a go

Comment: Sure, let me know if it works, will try to fix it :)

Comment: OK I have setup JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RedEarthDesigns/uwXf6/3/

Comment: I'm having troubles understanding what you are trying to achieve. If you want your .hidden container to span the entire height of the cell, then all you have to do is actually set `.hidden{height: 100%;}`. Right now only the inner span has 100% height, which means that it will merely fill the .hidden div and not the entire cell.

Comment: Hey @danielpervan, Unfortunatly that hasn't worked.. I am trying to achieve a rollover effect, that when the background image is rolled over it disappears and the text remains..

Comment: Ok, so it's not something like this you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/uwXf6/4/

Comment: Holy Crap @DanielPerván! that's awesome.... thats exactly what I'm after.. :)

Comment: Hey @DanielPerván Do you know why the text alignment is not stuck at the top right?? rather than bottom right? If not all good, this design will still work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! So @DanielPerván has answered the question, and put up a JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/uwXf6/4/

**HTML**

```
<div class="div-table">
    <div class="div-td venue">
        <div class="hidden"><span><h1>Venue Name</h1><p>Venue Address</p><p>Venue Website</p> <p>More Info</p></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-td venue">
        <div class="hidden"><span><h1>Venue Name</h1><p>Venue Address</p><p>Venue Website</p><p>More Info</p></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400, 300);
 body {
    margin:0;
    font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background-color:#111;
}
p {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#eee;
    line-height: 6px;
}
h1 {
    font-size:24px;
    color:#eee;
}
.div-table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.div-row {
    display:table-row;
}
.div-td {
    display:table-cell;
    height:33%;
    width:20%;
    text-align:right;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.hidden span {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width:auto;
    vertical-align:text-bottom;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-transform:translate(500px);
    -moz-transform:translate(500px);
    transform:translate(500px);
    opacity:0;
    display:block;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s, opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .5s, opacity 1s;
    transition: transform .5s, opacity 1s;
}
.hidden:hover span {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width:auto;
    vertical-align:text-bottom;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-transform:translate(0);
    -moz-transform:translate(0);
    transform:translate(0);
    opacity:1;
}
.venue {
    background-image:url(http://www.indpg.com.au/img/norman.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.div-td:hover {
    background-image:none;
}

.hidden {
     height: 100%;   
}
```

Works Perfectly! Awesome!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your best choice is using inline-block elements and box-size:border box property, imho.

```
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">some content</div>
  <div class="row">some content</div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
 body, html {height:100%;}
.wrapper {height:100%;box-sizing:border-box;background:black;}
.row {background:red;display:inline-block;width:30%;height:100%;}
```

[box-sizing: border-box](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) solves many things in such layouts and makes every other need much easier to achieve.

[Here's a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/CkNTk/) in jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks! but not quite what I was after!